# jQuery handling promises from multiple Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm a newbie in jQuery and Ajax world, so the resolution might be easier than I imagine, however I'm bouncing my head against the wall for the past day to resolve a following scenario.

I have a list of tasks.
There's a checkbox next to each task, so it can be selected and "Approved" in a batch. Approval from business perspective means - create new item in Sharepoint and delete the current item.

Approval function, being fired for each selected item, consists of following chained functions:

- Function to prepare the payload (properties);
- ..which calls the function to prepare URI and other data;
- .. which calls the Ajax function;
- .. which, in case Ajax succeeeds (item is created), calls another Ajax function (to delete item);

The problem is - the user get's navigated away from the page before all the Ajax calls have been made and items created/deleted.

Because of this messed up structure, I created a global array, and executed a push after each Ajax call (GlobalArray.push(Ajax)), but this returns an *undefined* at the end.

I tried to somehow pass the Ajax variable up this tree of functions, but when queried at the initial function, it again returns *undefined*.

Could someone, please, point me to a right direction?